# if a non-correlated subquery is repeated at several places in the query, can it be cached and the result reused?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, postgresql-9.1

If I have a query like

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', assigndate)e,
       count(CASE WHEN a.assigneeid = 65548
             AND a.assigneeid IN
               (SELECT userid
                FROM groupmembers
                WHERE groupid = 65553) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) assigned,
       count(CASE WHEN a.assigneeid = 65548
             AND a.completedtime IS NOT NULL
             AND a.assigneeid IN
               (SELECT userid
                FROM groupmembers
                WHERE groupid = 65553) THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) completed
FROM ASSIGNMENT a
WHERE assigndate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '20 days'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day',assigndate);
```

The subquery in question is

```
SELECT userid
                FROM groupmembers
                WHERE groupid = 65553
```

then since the subquery is `not co-related` to the parent query, it will be executed just once and the cached result will be used. But since the subquery is present at 2 locations in the query, then according to the `SQL plan`, it is evaluated **twice**. Is there any way to `cache` the result of that subquery and use it at both the locations ?

The subquery can't be converted to a join as is no single field on which to join (and it can't be an unconditional join, as the count will become wrong then)

Comment: You appear to have a redundant expression. There's no point in having a clause saying "a.assigneeid = 65548" and "a.assigneeid in (subquery)" - they're either both true or both false.

Comment: It was just for demonstrative reasons (bad logic, though!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use a common table express ([`WITH`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-with.html))

```
with cte as 
(
     SELECT userid FROM groupmembers WHERE groupid = 65553
)
SELECT 
    date_trunc('day', assigndate)e,  
    count(CASE WHEN a.assigneeid = 65548 AND a.assigneeid IN  
           (SELECT userid from cte) then 1 else null end) assigned,
...
```

Comment: Another variation of this would be to use a temporary table and join to it so that you are only executing that given statement once.

Comment: In SQL Server, this does *not* guarantee that the subquery will run only once.  Does Postgres guarantee this?

Comment: @JustBob - there would be no way to join that temporary table with the assignment table, and the union will be unconditional, making the calculation of count wrong

Comment: It's [documented](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html): _A useful property of WITH queries is that they are evaluated only once per execution of the parent query, even if they are referred to more than once by the parent query or sibling WITH queries._

Comment: Oh yes. In the actual link I provided. D'oh :)

Comment: @GordonLinoff Woah, isn't that in violation of the standard? The SQL standard certainly requires `WITH` queries to be optimisation fences (which can be both useful and a pain). I don't know for sure that that requires single-execution, but I seem to remember it does.

Comment: @CraigRinger . . . I am unaware that the SQL standard makes such statements about optimization.  I can look at the execution plans for SQL Server, and see that the queries get executed for each reference.  Can you provide a reference?

Comment: @Daud I'm not saying use a CTE at all. Take the results of SELECT userid FROM groupmembers WHERE groupid = 65553 and put them in a temp table and join the original question's query to the temp table instead of putting SELECT userid FROM groupmembers WHERE groupid = 65553 in multiple times. That way you only scrape groupmembers once.

Comment: @DanielVérité . . . Thank you for the pointer.  I was actually refering to standards documentation.  I have no doubt that most SQL engines do the reasonable thing, which is what PostGres does.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm finding references to the requirement on the Pg mailing list, like http://osdir.com/ml/postgresql-pgsql-hackers/2012-10/msg00024.html and http://archives.postgresql.org/pgsql-hackers/2012-10/msg00027.php, but nobody's citing references. SQL:2008 isn't what you'd call *highly readable* and the only copy I have access to lacks niceies like PDF bookmarks. I haven't found what they're referring to.

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite the query to eliminate the subqueries:

```
SELECT date_trunc('day', assigndate)e,
       sum(CASE WHEN a.assigneeid = 65548 and gm.userid is not null then 1 else 0
           end) as assigned,
       sum(CASE WHEN a.assigneeid = 65548 and a.completedtime IS NOT NULL and gm.userid is not null
                then 1 else 0
           end) as completed
FROM ASSIGNMENT a left outer join
     (select distinct userid
      from groupmembers
      where groupid = 65553
     ) gm
     on a.assigneeid = gm.userid
WHERE assigndate > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '20 days'
GROUP BY date_trunc('day',assigndate)
order by 1
```

In general, I think it is good practice to keep table references in the `FROM` (or `WITH`) clauses.  It can be hard to follow the logic of subqueries in the `SELECT` clause.  In this case, the subqueries are so somilar that they are practically begging to be combined into a single statement.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the similarity, but in the actual scenario, there is a count clause with approverid too. As such, I can't do a join on assigneeid