# How to optimize a MySQL update which contains an "in" subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I optimize the following `update` because the sub-query is being executed for each row in table a?

```
update 
  a 
set 
  col = 1 
where 
  col_foreign_id not in (select col_foreign_id in b)
```

Comment: Is that even correct SQL?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011280/if-a-non-correlated-subquery-is-repeated-at-several-places-in-the-query-can-it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could potentially use an outer join where there are no matching records instead of your `not in`:

```
update table1 a
    left join table2 b on a.col_foreign_id = b.col_foreign_id
set a.col = 1
where b.col_foreign_id is null
```

This should use a simple select type rather than a dependent subquery.

Your current query (or the one that actually works since the example in the OP doesn't look like it would) is potentially dangerous in that a NULL in b.col_foreign_id would cause nothing to match, and you'd update no rows.

`not exists` would also be something to look at if you want to replace `not in`.

I can't tell you that this will make your query any faster, but there is some good info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2246772/whats-the-difference-between-not-exists-vs-not-in-vs-left-join-where-is-null).  You'll have to test in your environment.

Here's a [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b5dec/1) illuminating the differences between in, exists, and outer join (check the rows returned, null handling, and execution plans).